# Archivos en un directorio en Java

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo un programa en el cual quiero saber qué contiene una carpeta/directorio "x".

Imaginaros que mi ruta "C:\Users\Nombre\Desktop\emoji" existe y contiene:

- 2 subcarpetas dentro de emoji (dentro de cada una, 3 archivos)
- 14 ficheros - sin contar los 6 anteriores -

En total: 2 carpetas y 20 ficheros.

**¿Cómo puedo averiguar desglobar los ficheros y carpetas que tenga una ruta "x"?** ¿Puedo separar los ficheros de las carpetas? Quiero imprimir cuántos ficheros (aunque haya subcarpetas en la carpeta global) hay en la carpeta "emoji" y cuántas carpetas hay.

**Código:**

```
import java.io.File;

public class ListarArchivosCarpeta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File ruta = new File("C:\\Users\\Nombre\\Desktop\\emoji");
        //Almacenamos en un array de tipo String todos los archivos de la carpeta.
        String[] listado = ruta.list();
        File[] listadoFich = ruta.listFiles();

        //Si existe la ruta del directorio...
        if (ruta.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Existe la ruta/carpeta/directorio.");

            if (listado == null || listado.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Hay "+listado.length+" elementos en la carpeta.");
                for (int i = 0; i < listado.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Nombre: "+listado[i]);
                }
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO existe ningún directorio.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *¿Puedo separar los ficheros de las carpetas?* Mira los métodos de la clase *File*.

Comment: ¿Quieres que se imprima toda la ruta del archivo? Es decir C:\Users\Nombre\Desktop\\emoji\carpetaX\archivoX.algo  dentro de la carpeta emoji?

O solo quieres saber el numero de archivos?

Comment: Quiero que se imprima cada subcarpeta y archivos y quiero contar, al final, cuantos ficheros hay y cuantas carpetas hay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te mostraré dos formas, una es usando una función recursiva. Esto a la vieja escuela

```
public static void buscar(final File folder) {
        for (final File f : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File: " + f.getName());
            }
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Carpeta: " + f.getName());
                buscar(f);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y digamos que esto se basa en que cuando se lee la ruta, bastara preguntar si es un archivo o un directorio. Entonces en caso que sea directorio volvemos a recorrer dicho directorio.

Otra forma es usando Java 8 Files Walk

```
public static void usandoJava8() {
        try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Nombre\\Desktop\\emoji"))) {

            List<String> result = walk.map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            result.forEach(System.out::println);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Y lo implementamos así:

```
 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File ruta = new File("C:\\Users\\Nombre\\Desktop\\emoji");
    //Almacenamos en un array de tipo String todos los archivos de la carpeta.
    //listado no se usa
    String[] listado = ruta.list();
    File[] listadoFich = ruta.listFiles();

    //Si existe la ruta del directorio...
    if (ruta.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Existe la ruta/carpeta/directorio.");

        if (listadoFich == null || listadoFich.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("No hay elementos dentro de la carpeta actual.");
        } else {
            buscar(ruta);
            usandoJava8();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO existe ningún directorio.");
    }

}
```

En caso que uses walk y solo quieres mostrar el nombre del archivo puedes usar

```
List<String> result = walk.map(x -> x.getFileName().toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: En el método de Java8 me da un error en la línea List<String> result = walk.map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());. ---> type List does not take parameters.

Comment: Lo mas seguro estas usando otro tipo de List. Valida en tus import. Yo use `import java.util.*;` Lo más seguro estas utilizando `java.awt.List`. En caso que no quieras usar import java.util.*; usa en su lugar `java.util.List`